# Close application when call startActivityForResult second time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a MainActivity and ManagerActivity. The MainActivity is LAUNCHER. My expected process as

> MainActivity (by startActivityForResult) >ManagerActivity >MainActivity (onBackPressed)+startActivityForResult>ManagerActivity >MainActivity

However, in second calling of startActivityForResult, the application is closed. It is similar as

> MainActivity (by startActivityForResult) >ManagerActivity >MainActivity (onBackPressed)+startActivityForResult>ManagerActivity >close app

I have no idea what is problem in my code. Could you suggest to me the way to obtain the above my expected proceduce

This is my code

```
 //MainActivity (by startActivityForResult) >ManagerActivity 
 Intent intentcontent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagerActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intentcontent, 1);

//On ManagerActivity                
 String  content_name    = "name";
 Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("content", content_name);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent dataIntent) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode ==  1) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //OK received detail
                }
            }    
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();  
    Intent intentcontent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentcontent, 1);

}
```

Comment: maybe am dumb but could you explain further? where is it closing?could you show code for both Mainactivity and manager activity?

Comment: Close mean application exit. I shows all in the above

Comment: The `super.onBackPressed();` call is finishing `MainActivity`. Also, you shouldn't be starting an Activity in `onBackPressed()`, as that's just confusing for the user.

Comment: I don't know it. So, If I click back button, How can I open the ManagerActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

chances are your activity is being destroyed by `onBackPressed` call it like this

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
startActivity(new Intent(this, myActivity.class));
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
```

atleast this is how i Call mine and I never get funny results like you are.

Comment: I want to get result from onActivityResult, so I want to use startActivityForResult function.

Comment: yes replace `startactivtiy` with `Intent intentcontent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentcontent, 1)`

Comment: and do not finish the activity like i did, I always finish mine incase the activitymanager does not and think of better logic, it is so confusing.

Comment: I tried it. It did not work. However, I found the solution. It is             Intent icontent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManageActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(icontent, PICK_LISTVIEW_REQUEST_BACK);  and delete the line super.onBackPressed(); and finish();

Comment: congratulations but I advice you change your logic, instead of user always clicking back button to go back to the calling activity how about you create a button labeled something like `ok` or `done` that is more intuitive and less confusing, how is a user suppose to know what to do next in your case? all users know back button will probably exit the app not `performing` a fundamental action like that